# How do I hide an svg and show another when using a phone?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I'm developing a web app with react strap. I am using 2 SVG's for background and I want one to be shown only when user access it from pc and another one should only be shown when user access it on Thier phone. So basically I want the 1st SVG to be hidden when user access website with their phone and vice versa

Comment: Have a look at `media queries` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 2):

A simple and elegant solution would be to apply bootstrap classes `hidden-xs` and `visible-xs` on the parent html element of the svg to be shown on pc and the svg to be shown on mobile respectively.

**How it works:**

1. All the classes with `-xs` as the suffix apply their effects only when the viewport is below 480px.
2. So in the case of `hidden-xs`, the element on which this class is applied will get *hidden* whenever the viewport resolution is below 480px. On higher resolutions, it will be *shown* by default.
3. And in the case of `visible-xs`, the element on which this class is applied will only be *shown* when the viewport resolution is below 480px. On higher resolutions, it will be *hidden* by default.

Example:

```
<div class="visible-xs">
  <svg /> <-- This will be shown on mobile and hidden on desktop --!>
</div>
<div class="hidden-xs">
 <svg /> <-- This will be hidden on mobile and shown on desktop --!>
</div>
```

In Bootstrap 4, this can be achieved by using the classes of the following format:

- `.d-{value}` for **xs**
- `.d-{breakpoint}-{value}` for **sm**, **md**, **lg**, and **xl**.

Where *value* is one of:

- none
- inline
- inline-block
- block table
- table-cell
- table-row
- flex
- inline-flex

Comment: hidden-*-up or hidden-*-down are not mentioned in the bootstrap 4 specs, the way to achieve this functionality through bootstrap 4 is to use the display classes having the format `d-{breakpoint}-{value}`

Comment: you are right, i keep getting the alpha specs... removed the comment

Comment: @ThomasScheffer no issues.. I updated my answer to include bootstrap 4 classes also.

Answer (score 1):

check to see if its mobile, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

and

```js
var isMobile = false
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) { 
    isMobile = true;
}

if(isMobile) {
  svg1.style.visibility = "hidden"
  svg2.style.visibility = "visible"
} else {
  svg2.style.visibility = "hidden"
  svg1.style.visibility = "visible"
}
```

```html
<svg id=svg1 width=200 height=200>
  <circle cx=70 cy=67 r=50 />
</svg>

<svg id=svg2 width=200 height=200>
  <circle cx=120 cy=100 r=50 />
</svg>
```

I believe its in your best interest to extract isMobile into a seperate function